# How to update the document from the C#.net

Tags: soap-api, document

I have upload the file from the c#.net by using the following code and document created successfully in Salesforce org.

```
 sforce.Document docvar = new sforce.Document();
            docvar.Name = documentName;
            docvar.Description = description;
            docvar.FolderId = folder.id;
            string extension = fileinfo.Extension;
            docvar.Type = extension.Replace(".", "");

            sforce.SaveResult saveResult = SFDCService.create(new sforce.sObject[] { docvar})[0];
            return saveResult;
```

**I dont know how to update the document. I have tried following code. But no luck.**

```
sforce.QueryResult qr = null;
            string SOQL = "";
            SOQL = "select id,name,description from document where id='" + _documentId + "'"; 
            qr = SFDCService.query(SOQL);
            sforce.sObject[] records1 = qr.records;

            sforce.Document doc = (sforce.Document)records1[0];

            sforce.SaveResult saveResult = SFDCService.update(new sforce.sObject[] {doc})[0];
            return saveResult;
```

Can you let me know how to update when click the update button form the c#.

Comment: What does your save result give you for errors? What happens when you attempt the update? Are you positive that the _documentId variable is actually populated with a salesforce documents ID and not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and you are jsut fetching the record and update without assign the new value.

Please use the follwoing code to resolve the issue.

```
qr = SFDCService.query(SOQL);
            sforce.sObject[] records1 = qr.records;
            sforce.Document doc = (sforce.Document)records1[0];
            doc.Name = documentName;
            doc.Url = filePath;
            sforce.SaveResult saveResult = SFDCService.update(new sforce.sObject[] {doc})[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating an empty document.

you need to set either the **Body** or **URL** parameter of the document while creating..

and then when updating you can replace the URL or the Body of the document and call the update method

you can [check this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_document.htm) for the api object and the fields

Comment: Crated is working fine. I am uploading the file by choosing from open dialog box. can you look the code. in where I miss. because i have assign the record to new doc. but it is not updated